# Electron: electron-packager: command not found

Tags: bash, electron, packages

Não estou conseguindo criar o aplicativo utilizando o **`electron`**.

Faço a instalação do pacote e quando vou executar o comando:

```
electron-packager d/dev/puxa Puxa
```

Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> **"Bash: electron-packager: command not found".**

```js
$ npm install electron-packager -g

oaming\npm\node_modules\electron-packager\cli.js

+ electron-packager@13.0.1

updated 1 package in 6.641s

$ electron-packager /d/[
```

> **"bash: electron-packager: command not found*".**

Comment: Tente isso: npm install -g electron-packager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma.

No arquivo .json adicione

```
 "scripts": {
 "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
"package-win": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Coloque aqui o nome da aplicacao\"",    
"package-linux": "electron-packager . electron-tutorial-app --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
 }
```

No bash execute

```
 npm run packager-win
```